# How to place cursor after lines appended in function

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

I have, for many years, used Vim.  Until today, I've not found the need for writing my own functions.  I found myself faced with adding some features to existing code, and in so doing needed to maintain a pattern.  To make life easier, I wrote

```
function! CompConst()
    let constName = toupper(input("Compiler Constant: "))
    let defBlock = ['#define ' . constName . '_SUFFIX_1',
                \'#define ' . constName . '_SUFFIX_2',
                \'#define ' . constName . '_SUFFIX_3',
                \'#define ' . constName . '_SUFFIX_4']
    call append(line('.'), defBlock)
endfunction

imap <C-d> <C-o>:call CompConst()<cr>
```

The function works marvelously except ... the cursor is left above the lines just inserted.  Yes, this does make sense because I'm using `append()`.  I looked through the help and `insert()` seems to apply to lists.  I haven't yet found a function for inserting text at the current line number.  Googling for **insert functions** and **insert** just reveals a whole lot of hits for the Ex commands.  I even tried a bit of *sleight-of-hand* and used `call append('.-1', defBlock)` which did the same as what's above.

If it matters, I'm using Vim 8.0 with patches 1-1453.

Comment: Try adding snippets, https://youtu.be/XA2WjJbmmoM

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Glad you were able to solve your problem!

Comment: @Mani +1 to the recommendation to use snippets! It's definitely the right tool for the job!

Comment: Simply `put =defBlock`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered modifying the function to move the cursor after the list insertion? This worked in my Vim (v8.1.7777)

```
function! CompConst()
    let constName = toupper(input("Compiler Constant: "))
    let defBlock = ['#define ' . constName . '_SUFFIX_1',
                \'#define ' . constName . '_SUFFIX_2',
                \'#define ' . constName . '_SUFFIX_3',
                \'#define ' . constName . '_SUFFIX_4']
    call append(line('.'), defBlock)
    norm! 4jo
endfunction
```

Comment: Yes, I did.  It didn't work.  I saw that your suggestion was to simply place the _normal_ command after the _<CR>_.  I had originally tried `imap ...<cr><c-o>4j`.  I tried what you have and the result is the same, it doesn't work.  Instead, the characters after the **<CR>** are simply placed into the `input()` waiting for me to press enter.

Comment: Apologies, I initially misread the imap for an nmap. I have since modified my response with a working function.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se] @ThatsWhatSheCoded! Nice first contribution. Personally, I would do `-4` instead of `normal! 4j` to move the cursor down 4 lines, but I just prefer ex commands over normal when ex will do :)

Comment: Thank you for the warm welcome, @D. Ben Knoble♦! Wouldn't it be `+4` instead of `-4` for the ex command since we're trying to move the cursor down 4 lines?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I think you mean `+4`  `-` is up, `+` is down...

Comment: @filbranden /facepalm yep.

Comment: Welcome @ThatsWhatSheCoded!

Comment: Thanks.  That seems to work nicely.  I hadn't considered using that command in this context.  I use extensively in with `:g` commands, but as I mentioned, before yesterday, I haven't done anything with Vim Script (other than tweak my rc file).